# Python socket recv

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I need to implement a simple network communication protocol.
I use Python 3.7. The program works in "localhost" mode. However, on LAN it doesn't work well. I initiate the `socket` via `socketserver`.

I manage to establish connection, but sometimes in `recv` the program simply hangs out infinitely. It manages to pass a few kilobytes but then randomly blocks everything.

Blocking mode is set to true, so I'd understand if data wasn't sent but the other side sent the information. So what happened? Did the information not arrive? Or was deleted for some reason?

Is there a reliable method to check if the message arrived (by the sender) and resent data if needed?

```
def ReceiveRaw(self, msgLen):
    msgOut = bytearray()
    totalReceived = 0
    while totalReceived < msgLen:
        chunk = self.sock.recv(min(msgLen - totalReceived,2048)) #sometimes hangs here infinitely

        if len(chunk) == 0:
            raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
        totalReceived+= len(chunk)

        for b in chunk:
            msgOut.append(b)

    return msgOut
```

Comment: I can't tell how this method fits in with `socketserver` framework.

Comment: [tag:serversocket] is a `java.net` class., not a Python component.

Comment: @user207421 well, `socketserver` is a Python component which I used.
Sry if it got mangled with java's `serversocket`